# Lora SX1276, RegPaConfig

Tags: lora

I am trying to develop my own LoRa SX1276 library. I can't understand the difference between MaxPower and OutputPower in the RegPaConfig to set transmission power.

Thanks in advance.

[image: register description]

Answer (score 0):

They're used sequentially for the setup:

- Set `PaSelect` (0 or 1).
- Set `Pmax` (`MaxPower` = 0 to 7) Pmax = 10.8 + 0.6 * MaxPower
  So if MaxPower is 7, Pmax = 15
- Then you calculate `Pout`, based on `PaSelect` and `OutputPower`.

  - If PaSelect = 0 then Pout = Pmax - (15 - OutputPower)

    - So, if `OutputPower` = 15, Pout = 15 - (15 - 15) --> 15
  - Else if PaSelect = 1 then Pout = 17 - (15 - OutputPower)

    - So, if `OutputPower` = 15, Pout = 17 - (15 - 15) --> 17

But these calculations are done by the chip. You don't need to do this. You just need to set the bit fields properly, PaSelect, MaxPower, and OutputPower. It's up to the user to set them properly.

If you want, `MaxPower` is a numerical shortcut the theoretical limit to the power the RF power amplifiers are allowed push. And `OutputPower` another shortcut to help the chip calculate the actual value.

Default values are 0, 4, 15 for `PaSelect`, `MaxPower` and `OutputPower`. For max performance you set them to 1, 15, 15. But whether that's legal in your country is another story.